# String input by linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Is there any way to take a string input(as like we take for any integer) by linked list??

For example:This code is showing run time error:

```
struct node
{
    char c;
    struct node *link;
};
while(1)
{
    val=getch();
    if(val!=10)
         add(&a[i],val);
    else
        break;
 }
```

and I want to take any input string like - `"asdfghj"`, of which string length was not known?

Comment: Which language? C++ or C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example for C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    char c;
    struct node *link;
} Node;

typedef struct s_ {
    Node *top;
    Node *curr;
} String;

Node *Node_new(char ch){
    Node *p = calloc(1, sizeof *p);
    p->c = ch;
    return p;
}

String *String_new(void){
    String *p = calloc(1, sizeof *p);
    return p;
}

void String_drop(String *s){
    Node *p = s->top;
    while(p){
        s->curr = p;
        p = p->link;
        free(s->curr);
    }
    //s->top = s->curr = NULL;
    free(s);
}

void String_add(String *s, char c){
    if(s->top == NULL){
        s->curr = s->top = Node_new(c);
    } else {
        s->curr = s->curr->link = Node_new(c);
    }
}

String *get_string(FILE *fp){
    String *s = String_new();
    int ch;
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && ch !='\n'){
        String_add(s, (char)ch);
    }
    return s;
}

void put_string(String *s){
    Node *p;
    for(p = s->top; p ; p = p->link)
        putchar(p->c);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void) {
    String *s = get_string(stdin);
    put_string(s);
    String_drop(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that you have a `LinkedList`-class that acts as an interface to the linked list and that it has the function `addNode()` that adds a `node` in a correct manner to the list. 
   I also assume that what you want to know is how to make every `char` in the inputted `string` a `node` in the linked list and that you know how to manage a linked list.

And assuming you're using C++11

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList list;
    string input;
    cin >> input;

    for(auto i: input)
    {
        list.addNode(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think easily. As You just can declare a string variable instead of char. And after that You can take input normally by creating a struct variable. For example:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using  namespace std;

struct node
{
    string s;
    struct node *link;
};


int main(){

     node ob;

     cin>>ob.s;
     cout<<ob.s;

}
```